# htaccess redirect url with different folders and parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to redirect a url in `.htaccess` from:

```
domain_name.com/folder/index.php?param=0
```

to:

```
domain_name.com/another_folder/page.html
```

How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^another_folder/page([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\.html$ folder/index.php?param=$1
```